# Got "Module did not self-register" error. when tried to added msnodesqlv8 module in electron

Tags: electron, mssql-jdbc, electron-packager, node-sqlserver

I got error when I had added msnodesqlv8 module in electron.

```
Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register.
at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at connectionModule (C:\Users\Gaurav\Documents\Electron Example\DesktopApplication\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\connection.js:10:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gaurav\Documents\Electron Example\DesktopApplication\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\connection.js:450:3)
```

I have try to connect my electron code to mssql with windows authentication. So I have added msnodesqlv8 module. But i got error in this line

```
var sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?